# Error: expected initializer before 'bool'

Tags: boolean, initializer

I have this header file and GNU GGC compiler gives me error in row with declaration of bool function. I cannot find anything wrong.

```
#ifndef GAMECREATOR_H
#define GAMECREATOR_H

bool isPerfectSquare (int x);

#endif // GAME_CREATOR_H
```

Comment: What language is that? C? C++?

Comment: C++. I probably find an issue. Error was in completely different file in project missing ";" but for whatever reason compiler give this error. After the correction in different file, compiler compiled this header without any errors.